# Spring boot and Socket IO Arduino Client

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, websocket, socket.io, arduino

I'm working server side using spring boot and i want to use an Arduino socket IO client to communicate with my spring boot web server.

I assume i will use this library for Arduino :

https://github.com/timum-viw/socket.io-client

But when i searched for spring boot socket IO server side implementation i always found reference to web sockets not socket IO.

Would there be be a problem in using web sockets for spring boot server side to communicate with Arduino socket IO client library ?

Answer (score 0):

I know the name socketio from a javascript library that implement the web socket protocol. From a quick look at it, the arduino lib  seems to be a clone for arduinos an ESP boards. So I would say, every lib that handles the web socket protocol is compatible with the Arduino socket-io implementation.